# Luks container isn't unlocked before trying to mount root

Tags: boot, luks

What do I need in my kubuntu 18.04 setup to make it decrypt a luks container (using passphrase) before trying to mount root? Simply adding an appropriate entry to /etc/crypttab and then updating grub didn't help. Using "root=/dev/mapper/ssd_encrypted_volume_group-root_logical_volume ro cryptdevice=/dev/sdb3:ssd_crypt_container" as kernel arguments in /etc/default/grub and then updating grub didn't help either. The system still doesn't ask me for a passphrase, instead it reports that it "Gave up waiting for root file system device" and goes into busybox.

Answer (score 0):

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

This solved it for me.